# SQL Insert using a Where clause

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a query that will only insert data if the data does not exist in the table already.  Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO JobTable (JobTitleName)
VALUES ('PROGRAMMER') 
WHERE JobTitleName NOT EXISTS(SELECT JobTitleName FROM
JobTable x WHERE x.JobTitleName = 'PROGRAMMER')
```

I am getting an error on the "where" clause.  I am sure the answer is easy, I am simply drawing a blank.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `where JobTitleName not in (select ....)`? Looking at your query again it doesn't really make sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: `INSERT` doesn't have a `WHERE` clause (as the [wonderful, official SQL Server Books Online documentation clearly shows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) ) - those rows that you specify (either by providing values, or a `SELECT` statement) are being inserted - so just don't provide those values you don't want to insert ....

Comment: If you want a where clause you need to run a full SELECT statement and not use the VALUES keyword. Write a SELECT query that has the records you want and then add the INSERT INTO line above it.

Comment: Maybe make JobTitleName the primary key... then you won't have to worry about duplicating it bc the database won't let you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an IF statement to test for the existence of the value in question.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT JobTitleName 
                  FROM JobTable x 
                  WHERE x.JobTitleName = 'PROGRAMMER')
    INSERT INTO JobTable 
        (JobTitleName)
        VALUES 
        ('PROGRAMMER');
```

Comment: I knew I was drawing a blank.  I used:IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT JobTitleName FROM CACDashboardsJobTitle x WHERE x.JobTitleName = 'JOE TEST')
INSERT INTO CACDashboardsJobTitle (JobTitleName)
VALUES ('JOE TEST')

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `where` clause in an `insert`, but you can use a query as source for the insert, and that can have a `where`.

Join in the `JobTable` with a `left join` so that you can make the query return zero records if the job title already exists:

```
insert into
    JobTable (JobTitleName)
select
    x.Title
from
    (select 'PROGRAMMER' as JobTitleName) x
    left join JobTable j on j.JobTitleName = x.JobTitleName
where
    j.JobTitleName is null
```